# Ask a user to input fileName that I later read

Tags: java, file, encryption

My task that I am working on is to ask a User to input a fileName they wish to encrypt. Right now I am focusing on getting it to read out, but I receive the fileNotFound exception. The file is located in the same folder as the app and is spelled correctly with a .txt. This is my code that I have so can anyone pick up the mistake?

```
case '1': {
    System.out.println("Enter The name of the File you wish to Encrypt: ");
    String inputFile = scanner.next();
    
    try {
        File file = new File(inputFile);
        Scanner myReader = new Scanner(file);
        while (myReader.hasNextLine()) {
            String msg = myReader.nextLine();
            System.out.println(msg);
        }
        myReader.close();
    } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
        System.out.println("An error occurred.");
        e.printStackTrace();
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: what is the path you are entering?

Comment: Just because the file is in the same path as the app, doesn't mean that's where the app is being executed from. It could be located in a different directory (such as the build directory, or someplace else).

Comment: Are you running this from an IDE or from the console?  Some projects such as Maven project has a specific folder where all your resource files must go in.  Otherwise, you would need the full path to the file.

Comment: Interesting, what would be an example of the path I should be entering in this scenario?

Comment: I am running it in IntelliJ IDEA

Comment: Give the full path value to the file. E.g, c:\My Documents\some_file.txt at the prompt.

Comment: Great it works! just had to add ' \src\'plaintext.txt,

Answer (score 0):

Either supply the full path to the file you want loaded at the prompt, or if you're running it from IntelliJ you can put the file in the root of your project directory and just enter the filename at the prompt and it will be loaded.